# Postgresql version 12.1 and SERIAL data type

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I had a simple table with following syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username TEXT NOT NULL,
  password TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Then I inserted a data with:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES("Hupen", "hupen123");
```

Here, according to documentation "id" field should auto increment itself, right? but It's not happening here. I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: Your insert statement is invalid SQL to begin with it won't even run.

Comment: Your query has a syntax error, using double quotes where it should have single quotes.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the use of `serial` [is discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don't_use_serial) in modern Postgres versions.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES('Hupen', 'hupen123');
```

That is:

- you need to enumerate the target columns for `insert`, otherwise the database expects you to provide values for all columns
- strings should be surrounded with single quotes - double quotes stand for identifiers (that's a syntax error in Postgres)

Comment: Yeah, I want to make id field auto increment automatically, every time I insert new data. How to achieve that?

Comment: @hupenpaija: that's what will happen with the above query. Since you are not passing a value to the column, it will auto-increment.

Comment: I get an error, "error: invalid input syntax for integer: "Hupen"". Is it expecting me to manually add data for id field? I am just switching from mysql, so I am new to postgres world.

Comment: @hupenpaija: you probably left out the part `(username, password)` in your query